# How to enforce JSON schema on a column

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column that I use to store json data in. 
What is the best way to enforce that data to comply to some json schema?

I know I can put a check constraint with a function to check against my requirements but is there a better/builtin way to do it?

Comment: Short answer: no. SQL Server has support for storing XML with a schema, but not JSON. There are of course workarounds where you validate the expression yourself, as you mention, and a custom CLR function could do anything, including pull in support for JSON schema validation if it really added value. That said, you should consider *why* you want a schema: if your data admits a fixed structure, consider using a table instead, SQL Server has very good support for those. :-) If, on the other hand, you want more solid support for JSON as your primary data, there are NoSQL alternatives.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Json is very flexible even if it does validate against a schema. All sort of conditions like `anyof` and `oneof` and even `if...else` are allowed in json schema - which might be hard to translate to a relational schema. That being said, I agree - Sql Server have some work ahead to fully support json properly - and schema validation might not be a top priority for them.

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this question, here is some more information on what built-in JSON support there does exist in SQL Server. Not a data type, but useful functions nonetheless. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15