Is there a way to enforce a specific JSON structure for JSON column?
I have a column in my table that will hold JSON objects. I currently have the column defined as MY_JSON_COLUMN NVARCHAR(MAX)
Is there a way to make sure the JSON adheres to a specific structure?
For example, before storing the JSON, check if the JSON has this specific structure
"
{
  name: '',
  description: '',
  friends: [
   {
     name: ''
     description: '',
   }
  ]
}
"

If possible, how can I make sure that the JSON has a structure exactly like the one above with all the keys included?
Is this something not possible on DB side but something that should be checked in Client side or backend before saving?
My idea is to have a master JSON template like above and use it as a sort of test checker to compare against the request JSON that is attempting to be stored

Sounds like you need Json schema. See https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/ValidatingJson.htm

Can the friends have friends also? Or does it only go down one level?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54903136/how-to-enforce-json-schema-on-a-column#comment96573766_54903136 - see upvoted comment

Not for the JSON. Though SQL Server supports XML Schema validation for a column of XML data type out of the box

@Charlieface It only goes down one level.

You should check this both in the app and in the database.
In the app, you should enforce this using an object model. For example:
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Friends { get; set; }
}

In SQL Server, you can use a CHECK constraint, although you can't check the array.
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT JsonMatching CHECK (
    ISJSON(MY_JSON_COLUMN) = 1 AND
    JSON_VALUE(MY_JSON_COLUMN, '$.name') IS NOT NULL AND
    JSON_VALUE(MY_JSON_COLUMN, '$.description') IS NOT NULL AND
    JSON_QUERY(MY_JSON_COLUMN, '$.friends') IS NOT NULL
);

The only way to recursively check the array would be to use a user defined function
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.IsJsonMatching (@json nvarchar(max))
RETURNS BIT
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS BEGIN
    RETURN
      CASE WHEN ISJSON(@json) = 0 OR
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM OPENJSON(@json)
          WITH (
           name nvarchar(4000),
           description nvarchar(4000),
           friends nvarchar(max) AS JSON
          ) j
        WHERE j.name IS NULL
           OR j.description IS NULL
           OR j.friends IS NOT NULL AND dbo.IsJsonMatching(j.friends) = 1
      ) THEN CAST(0 AS bit) ELSE CAST(1 AS bit) END;
END;

ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT JsonMatching CHECK (
    ISJSON(MY_JSON_COLUMN) = 1 AND dbo.IsJsonMatching(MY_JSON_COLUMN) = 1
);


However, I strongly recommend you don't go down this road. If your schema is strictly defined then you should use proper tables, not loosely defined JSON.
For example, a graph table could look like:
CREATE TABLE Node (
    Id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(1000) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE NodeFriend (
    Id bigint REFERENCES Node (Id),
    FriendId bigint REFERENCES Node (Id),
    PRIMARY KEY (Id, FriendId),
    INDEX IX_2 (FriendId, Id),
    CHECK (Id < FriendId)
);

